# LDA in Python, I got the code from GitHub, but I got some error, you can see the error in the attached screenshot

Tags: python, nlp, modeling, lda

This is my code

```py
import pyLDAvis
import pyLDAvis.gensim_models
import importlib
pyLDAvis.enable_notebook()
vis = pyLDAvis.gensim_models.prepare(lda_model, doc_term_matrix, dictionary)
vis
```

I got this error

```
  /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py in submit(self, fn, *args, **kwargs)
   1100         with self._flags.shutdown_lock:
   1101             if self._flags.broken is not None:
-> 1102                 raise self._flags.broken
   1103             if self._flags.shutdown:
   1104                 raise ShutdownExecutorError(

BrokenProcessPool: A task has failed to un-serialize. Please ensure that the arguments of the function are all picklable.
```

Also you can see the screenshot of the error

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: This question needs more context to answer -- more frames of the exception are needed, and information on the construction of lda_model is needed as well. Likely, some argument to pyLDAvis is not picklable, so is likely not of the intended input type.

Comment: https://github.com/rsreetech/LDATopicModelling/blob/main/LDADemo.ipynb  here is the code for details ,  i got the error in section 60 .